# How the address of the stored value in the memory comes back

Tags: javascript, variables, memory

when defining a variable

```
let foo = 'bar';
```

the value goes through the data bus, is stored in a random location in the memory and the address of that location is sent back through that address bus and the program saves the address alongside the variable within the activation object (an object where local variables are stored)

inversely, when invoking a variable, the associated address is sent through the address bus and a value found at that location is sent back via the data bus

I've just learned that the address bus is one directional, does this mean that the stored value address comes back through the data bus? Or my mental representation of the process is completely false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a high-level interpreted language, so there are *very* many levels of indirection before you can even think about address and data buses.

In fact, if you're running a program compiled from C, which is fairly low-level, on a modern operating system, there are *still* lots of layers inbetween (e.g. virtual memory).

Anyway:

> the value goes through the data bus

First you'd need to think about what the value is. There's no way for a (current) computer to think of a string `"bar"` as a single value. Let's consider a naive, simplified implementation of some sort of quasi-JavaScript where there are only integer numbers and ASCII characters. Here, your `"bar"` could be represented as about 5 bytes: one to mark this value as a string, then its length (and our quasi-JavaScript can only store strings up to 255 characters, i.e. one byte's worth), then the contents: `01 03 61 62 72`.

The JavaScript interpreter would:

- ask the runtime library it's using to allocate that much memory and get an address

  - the runtime library's allocator would figure out where in the process's virtual memory space it can fit 5 bytes
  - if it can't, it would ask the operating system's memory allocation machinery to give it 5 bytes (likely it would ask for more, just in case) (and this could fail if you're out of memory)
- having now a *virtual address*, write those five bytes there.
- the OS's and processor's virtual memory implementation will then map that virtual address to a real physical memory address, and then there will be a transaction using the address and data buses

> is stored in a random location in the memory and the address of that location is sent back through that address bus

There's no randomness here. There can't be any randomness here :) As discussed above, the OS and CPU know exactly where the data is and where it should be. And yes, the address bus between the CPU and RAM is unidirectional, so nothing comes back that way.

> the program saves the address alongside the variable within the activation object (an object where local variables are stored)

Such an "activation object" will also consume space in memory; in a JavaScript interpreter, it could be a hash table mapping strings (variable names) to their contents' addresses (as discussed above).

> inversely, when invoking a variable, the associated address is sent through the address bus and a value found at that location is sent back via the data bus

Thinking about "variables" is way too high-level at that point, but yes, "when accessing memory, ..."

---

Hope this helps. I'm sure I've forgotten some layers of indirection here (e.g. CPU cache!).